# Memory leak in ember-qunit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, memory-leaks, ember-cli

I've got a memory leak in my Ember-CLI app during unit testing.

I've got a pretty large test suite consisting of some 300+ tests. When I run all the tests in the suite at once, Chrome reaches it's per-tab 1,6 GB memory limit and crashes. Clearly that is unacceptable.

I've already collected a memory profile from running a single test. After test pass is complete, I see a lot of instances of `Class`, not really sure what they are. There are also some `HTMLBarsMorph` objects. I attach below some screenshots from the memory snapshot below.

**Question**: How do I diagnose a leak in an Ember-CLI application? Specifically, how could I find out what exactly is the garbage left on the heap - instances of `Class`, `HTMLBarsMorph` both seem pretty commonplace, so it doesn't help much.

It seems that some of the objects have `_state` set to `"destroying"`. That sounds wrong, no? I guess they should be in `"destroyed"` state, if anything.

[image: heap snapshot 1]
[image: heap snapshot 2]
[image: heap snapshot 3]
[image: heap snapshot 4]

**EDIT**:

Performed the following additional experiments:

1. Put 100 repetitions of a test that visits the home page and then quits. Memory leak is present.
2. Put 1000 repetitions of a test that only runs `beforeEach`, `afterEach` and `assert.ok(true)`. This time *there is no leak*.

This tells me that this has something to do with the remains of data needed for rendering / layout present after application is destroyed. This seems to be in accord with what I saw in the memory dumps.

**EDIT 2**:

Using comparison of memory snapshots I was able to get a few candidates for the root cause of the leak. Here are some candidates:

- Container
- TransitionState
- Registry
- Couple of DetachedDOM objects, however that in itself wouldn't cause Container to leak, for example.
- StarSegment (?)

Snapshots are separated by 10 test runs, to make leaking objects more visible. The first picture demonstrates a list of most likely culprits:

[image: list of leaking objects]

When I don't call `visit()` inside the test, there is no leak which is visible in the second set of snapshots:

[image: no leaking objects]

Comment: Might sound like something obvious but are you tearing down the app after each test? When a test is complete there shouldn't be anything left for the inspector to show (no ember app).

Comment: @Kitler: Yes, indeed, I tear down the app after the test, so I guess it's not that.

Comment: @Kitler: added some experiments that perhaps will tell you something.

Comment: This is really weird, are you on the ember community slack? If yes ask in the ember-cli channel

Comment: Okay, I'll ask. Thank you.

Comment: I’m working on a large Ember.js application and I have the same issue. `App.reset()` is called between each test. At first I thought it was a PhantomJS problem but it happens also with Firefox. In PhantomJS, with Ember.js 1.9.1 and 570 tests, the memory usage increases by around 500 MiB. With the same tests in Ember.js 1.10.0, it grows by more than 1200 MiB. Currently, with Ember 2.0 or 2.1, PhantomJS crashes after around 500 tests (out of 1000+) with a memory usage growing up by around 4 GiB.